# how to avoid spinner affect other place?

Tags: android, android-spinner

My code is very long so I will describe my problem. It's about the size and position of  a `Spinner`. My `ListView` has items, each item has a `TextView` and a `Spinner`. The data in `Spinner`s is different. I only operate data of the first one when I click the `Spinner`. It will pop out. The data in the `Spinner` comes from a list of database. When I edit the data (delete, move, add) in fact, I edit the data from an array. The question is when I pop out the spinner it will fill the whole screen, show at the centre of screen, the area around it will be gray and if I click the gray area the `Spinner` will hide again but I need it keep out state so I can do something about its data and don't affect the other area (the grey area). Would anyone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you need...

Comment: @fiddler hmm,I click the spinner,then the items will pop out ,but the spinner and its popout part stay in centre of screen.and other part of screen will be gray,if I click the gray part ,the popping part will back and hide again,but I need it stay and lock here,so I can operate the data in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to detect when the `Spinner` is hidden then you should implement `OnItemSelectedListener` in your `Activity`.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. Handle your data here
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // No item was selected
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think you misunderstand my question,what i want to reach is when i draw out the spinner ,if I click other place in the screen ,the spinner is still keep the state out,so I can operate its items,now my app is when i click the other place ,the spinner will back automatic

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the 'spinner is still keep the state out' or 'so I can operate its items' or 'the spinner will back automatic'

Comment: there are items in spinner,I click the spinner ,it will pop out ,so I can do something with the items of spinner ,hmm.spinner has frame,now if i click the area out of the frame ,the spinner will back again ,i have to click it once more,I don't want it back when i click other area.

Comment: I don't know of any way you can prevent it from disappearing. You could make it reappear as soon as it disappears withspinner.performClick();

Comment: Thanks, i will try,there is another question ,the spinner will affect other area in screen.when spinner pop out ,other area becoming gray,can't handle